# Problems reading in a file in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I'm having problems reading in files in C++. Ill include the relevant code and an example of my file. Thank you in advance.

```
string fileName;
cout << "Enter file name: ";
cin >> fileName;


ifstream inputFile(fileName);
if (inputFile.is_open()) {
    getline(inputFile, line);
    pNum = stoi(line);
    int i = 0;
    
    while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
        double x = stod(line.substr(0, line.find(" ")));
        double y = stod(line.substr(line.find(" ")));
        Point pTemp;
        pTemp.x = x;
        pTemp.y = y;
        p.push_back(pTemp);
        i++;
        cout << "File is open" << endl;
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
else {
    cout << "Problem reading input file" << endl;
}
```

**Txt file (file7.txt)**
5.63585 0.0125126
8.08741 1.93304
4.79873 5.85009
8.95962 3.50291
7.46605 8.2284
8.58943 1.74108
5.13535 7.10501

Comment: And what problem are you having with this code? Is it producing an error of some kind?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, even if I cin the name "file7.txt" it skips to "Problem reading the input file". I've gone step by step and im not sure whats wrong with it.

Comment: My guess would be, the current working directory is not what you think it is, and the file `file7.txt` is not in it.

Comment: Ill mess with that @IgorTandetnik, im new to the IDE I've been using

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the syntax your using, so maybe try this. Replace `ifstream inputFile(fileName);` with `ifstream inputFile;` then followed by `inputFile.open(fileName);`.

Comment: `ifstream inputFile(fileName);` is correct, so is your example. The OP has called the constrcutor of `ifstream` and passed the file name to it.

Answer (score 0):

It works! Im completely new to the IDE I've been using and @Igor was correct. I had the current working directory set wrong. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: There should be no `else` with your `if`. It should simply be `if (!inputFile.is_open()) { /* handle error */ exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }` By exiting if the open fails you save an entire level of indention throughout the remainder of your source file.